# Dependency Injection - single interface and multiple classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to understand the concept behind Dependency Injection. Assuming that I have an interface and concrete classes as below

```
public interface ILogger { void LogMe(); }

public class LogTextFile : ILogger
{
   public void LogMe()
   {
       //Do text file logging stuff
   }

 }

public class LogXMLFile :ILogger
{
   public void LogMe()
   {
       //Do XML file logging stuff
   }

}
```

### StructureMap setup

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
 x.For<ILogger>().Use<LogTextFile>();
});

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
 x.For<ILogger>().Use<LogXMLFile>();
});
```

The questions

1. Is this setup valid?
2. How do I request for an instance of LogXMLFile or LogTextFile at anytime as I needed. Is it going to create any ambiguity problem?

regards,

Alan

Comment: Hi, I think you should read about inversion of control (ioc) it is related to dependency injection but not quite the same. The big difference is about these kinds of setups. In your scenario: it is valid provided your resolver is able to distinguish between the types. This is usually done with a name parameter.

Comment: When do you need to to work with an LogXMLFile or LogTextFile directly. The whole idea with Dependency Inversion is that you program to an interface not an implementation, so the application should only know about ILogger and should not care to where it is logged.